# Finding value difference in column pairs

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL server 2008R2 and I have a view which returns the following:

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | col1A | col1B | col2A | col2B | col3A | col3B |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |     1 |     1 |     3 |     5 |     4 |     4 |
|  2 |     1 |     1 |     5 |     5 |     5 |     4 |
|  3 |     3 |     4 |     5 |     5 |     4 |     4 |
|  4 |     1 |     2 |     5 |     5 |     4 |     3 |
|  5 |     1 |     1 |     2 |     2 |     3 |     3 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

As you can see this view contains column pairs (col1A and col1B), (col2A and col2B), (col3A and col3B).

I need to query this view and find rows where the column pairs contain different values.
So I would be looking to return:

```
+----+------------+---+-----+
| ID | ColumnType | A |  B  |
+----+------------+---+-----+
|  1 | Col2       | 3 | 5   |
|  2 | Col3       | 5 | 4   |
|  3 | Col1       | 3 | 4   |
|  4 | Col1       | 1 | 2   |
|  4 | Col3       | 4 | 3   |
+----+------------+---+-----+
```

I think I need to use UNPIVOT but not sure how – appreciate any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008+ you can use `CROSS APPLY` to unpivot the pair of columns and then you can easily compare the values in the `A` and `B` to return the rows that don't match:

```
select t.ID,
    c.ColumnType,
    c.A,
    c.B
from [dbo].[yourview] t
cross apply
(
    values 
        ('Col1', Col1A, Col1B),
        ('Col2', Col2A, Col2B),
        ('Col3', Col3A, Col3B)
) c (ColumnType, A, B)
where c.A <> c.B;
```

If you have different datatypes in your columns, then you'll need to convert the data to the same type.  You can do this conversion within the `VALUES` clause:

```
select t.ID,
    c.ColumnType,
    c.A,
    c.B
from [dbo].[yourview] t
cross apply
(
    values 
        ('Col1', cast(Col1A as varchar(50)), Col1B),
        ('Col2', cast(Col2A as varchar(50)), Col2B),
        ('Col3', cast(Col3A as varchar(50)), Col3B)
) c (ColumnType, A, B)
where c.A <> c.B
```

Comment: Actually I had to revisit this and there is a problem.  
This works if all the columtypes are the same or compatible data types. But fails if for example col1A and Col1B are type INT and Col2A and col2B are of type Date then it fails with error:
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

I am not sure why this is the case because I thought the comparisons of values would be on the same column types (Col1A <> Col1B,  Col2A <> Col2B, Col3A <> Col3B)???

Comment: @user3801452 If the datatypes are not the same, then you would need to cast them to be the same datatype. You can perform this cast/convert inside the `values` clause.  When you convert multiple columns into a single column, then the type must be the same for everything stored.  If you have an int and datetime, then you would probably have to look at using a `varchar`.

Comment: thanks for that, i have INTs, varchars, dates and decimals.  i will test by using convert to varchar.